# How do threads know how to "go back" to a previously locked block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Consider this code: (Note: all try/catch removed for code clarity)

```
Object lock1 = new Object();
Object lock2 = new Object();
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void process() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        methodA();
        methodB();
    }
}

public void methodA() {

    synchronized (lock1) {
        Thread.sleep(1); // mimics other operations
        list1.add(random.nextInt(100));
    }
}

public void methodB() {

    synchronized (lock2) {
        Thread.sleep(1); // mimics other operations
        list2.add(random.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```

Now suppose 2 threads are created and both simply call the `process()` method in their `run()`.

Say when thread2 tries to access `methodA()`, the lock is already taken by thread1. From what I understood, thread2 will then skip the synchronized lock, exit `methodA()`, and start `methodB` (which is the point of having more than 1 lock object). But my question is how will thread2 then know to "go back up" and complete `methodA()`, instead of just continuing with the `for` loop?

I know this is the case because `list1` and `list2` both have 2000 `Integers` in them at the end, meaning that both threads successfully completed the `for` loop in `process()` 1000 times each, and called both methods each time.

My only guess would be that when a thread encounters a synchronized block that is locked, it stores that block in a queue (or its stack?) and moves on, until the block is free again.

Comment: Your understanding is fundamentally wrong.  When thread2 hits `synchronized(lock1)` and finds it's already locked, it **waits** until it's unlocked.  It will stay there, in `methodA`, until the lock is available.  It does not "skip" the lock, and it doesn't exit `methodA`.

Comment: You may want to try to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From what I understood, `thread2` will then skip the synchronized lock, exit methodA(), and start methodB

No, `thread2` will block, ie. stop execution, until the other thread has completed `methodA` and released the lock. It will then resume execution, acquire the lock, and execute the method.

Comment: Ah, got it. My confusion stemmed from not knowing how having 2 locks would then be quicker, but I reviewed the code with this in mind and now understand, thx

Answer (score 0):

MethodA() and methodB() is called sequencially so if the lock is there in methodA() until and unless the lock is clear the thread will be in blocked state.